# Listing databases in rockmongo

Tags: php, mongodb

I've got mongodb running in following configuration: 1 config server, 2 mongos, 8 shards (4 per mongos). I've got a problem using [rockmongo](http://code.google.com/p/rock-php/wiki/rock_mongo) administration tool:
if I connect to `mongos` router and try to list databases, I receive the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message 'no primary!' in     /home/vissi/var/www/rockmongo/app/models/MDb.php:5 ...
```

This problem exists only in one `mongos`, connecting to other `mongos` gives correct listing. Running `db.serverStatus()` in `mongo` console shows `... ok => 1` in both `mongos`.

if I connect to `mongod` running with shardsvr option, I see only `config` and `local` databases.

How should I connect to see all my databases correctly? [phpmoadmin](http://code.google.com/p/phpmoadmin-mongodb-admin-tool-for-php/) (and `mongo` console) runs `show dbs` ok.

*If you have more than 1500 reputation, please, add `rockmongo` tag to this question.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved updating `mongos` at one of the machines from 1.6.5 to 1.7.3.